# Showing contents of a LinkedStack without removing them

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java and I am currently working Nodes. I was wondering if there was a way to show the content of a list without having to use .getNext method, because once I use it, it removes the element that was on the Node well literally removes the Node on top. What I am trying to do in this code is using input  to store two String elements in the new two Nodes then using the method *proveTitle* to prove that those elements are on the list. Once I do that I make sure that elements are still intact and use the toString method to check the list. **Note that in the class of Book for some strange reason the
 T isnt showing besides the class and the implemented class if I put the <> around it.**

Heres the code:

## myNode class:

```
public class myNode<T> 
{

private T data;
private myNode next;

public myNode(T _data)
{
data = _data;
}
public myNode(T _data, myNode _next)
{
data = _data;
next = _next;
}

public T getData()
{
return data;    
}

public void setData(T _data)
{
data = _data;    
}

public myNode getNext()
{

return next;    
}

public void setNext(myNode _next)
{
 next = _next;   
}

}
```

## Interface class:

```
public interface myInterface<T> 
{
   public void pushTitle(T data);
   public T pop();
   public T peek();
   public String toString();
   public boolean isEmpty();
   public int size();
   public myNode getNode();
}
```

## Book class, which contains the methods

public class Book implements myInterface

```
{
 private int count;
 private T author;
 private T title;
 private int stock;

 private myNode<T> top;

 public Book()
 {
     count = 0;
     top = null;
 }

@Override
 public myNode getNode()
 {
 return top;
 }


 @Override
 public void pushTitle(T title)
 {
 myNode<T> current = new myNode<>(title, top);
 current.setNext(top);
 top = current;
 count++;
 }

 public void proveTitle(T title)
 {
  T result;

  myNode<T> current = top;   

  if(title.equals(current.getData()))
  {
  result = current.getData();
  System.out.println("The title " + "'" + result + "'" + " exist."); 
  top = top.getNext();



 }
 }

 @Override
 public T pop()
 {
 T result;
 if(count == 0 || top == null )
 {
     System.out.println("List is empty");
 }
 System.out.println("The element on top is:"  +  top.getData());
 result = top.getData();
 top = top.getNext();

 count--;
 return result;

 }
 @Override

 public T peek()
 {
     System.out.println("Element on top is: " + top.getData());
     return top.getData();
 }
 @Override
 public boolean isEmpty()
 {
     if(top == null)
     {
     System.out.println("The list is empty");
     }
     else
     {
       System.out.println("The list is not empty." + "It has" + count + "elements");    
     }

  return top == null;   
 }
 @Override
 public int size()
 {
     System.out.println("The size of the list is" + count);
 return count;    
 }
 @Override
 public String toString()
 {
  String result = "";
  myNode current = top;
  System.out.println("Top");
  while(current != null)
  {
  result += ("[" + current.getData() + "]\n");
  current = current.getNext();
  }
  return result + "Bottom";
 }

}
```

## main class:

```
package node;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class myDriver 
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  

    Book<String> title = new Book<>();



    myNode<String> current;
    current = title.getNode();
    String push;
    String push2;

    System.out.println("Enter title of book 1");
    push = input.nextLine();
    title.pushTitle(push);

    System.out.println("Enter title of book 2");
    push2 = input.nextLine();
    title.pushTitle(push2);

    title.proveTitle(push);
    title.proveTitle(push2);


    System.out.println(title.toString());






}
}
```

## Output:

```
run:
Enter title of book 1
Tiger
Enter title of book 2
crossed
The title 'crossed' exist.
Top
[Tiger]
Bottom
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be trying to implement a `List` using a `Stack`.  These are very different data structures.  What you are trying to do is very easy in a `List`.  In a `Stack` it requires that you have a second stack.  As you pop each object off the current stack, you push it onto the second stack.

If order doesn't matter, you can do this once and switch to using the second stack.  If order does matter, you will have to reverse the process to get back your original stack.

Also note that the better approach would probably be to just use a `List`.